# Error while using NZload

Tags: netezza

I am trying to use nzload to load a file residing in a unix directory to a NZ database but I keep getting the following error:

nzsql "nzload -u $NZ_USER -pw $NZ_PASSWORD -host $NZ_HOST -db $NZ_DATABASE -df  -lf log.txt -bf err.txt"

nzsql: database name exceeds limit

my database name is only 18 bytes

Where am I going wrong? Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two commands in one, NZSQL and NZLOAD are two different commands. Please use following command -

> user@domain dir]# nzload -u $NZ_USER -pw $NZ_PASSWORD -host $NZ_HOST -db $NZ_DATABASE
>   -df your_file_name -lf log.txt -bf err.txt

Hope this will help.